# What is the probability of getting heads or a 4?

Tags: probability, fractions

*When a coin is flipped and a die is thrown, what is the probability of getting a heads or a 4 ?*

**What I've tried:**

P(Getting Heads) = $\frac12$

P(Getting a 4) = $\frac16$

Thus, P(Getting Heads **or** 4) $= \frac12 + \frac16$
$ =\frac23$

But the right answer is $\frac{7}{12}$.
 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The events are not mutually exclusive. $P(\text{Getting Heads or 4}) = 1 - P(\text{Not Getting Heads AND Not Getting a 4}) = 1 -  P(\text{Not Getting Heads}) P(\text{Not Getting a 4}) = 1 - (\frac{1}{2})(\frac{5}{6})$

Comment: $P("head" \cup "4")=P("head")+P("4")-P("head" \cap "4")=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{7}{12}$

Comment: So, "or" is basically "Union" ?

Comment: @WhiteFlameAB "Union" means **at least** A or B.

Comment: @calculus But you have found the **Union** in your comment. Does this mean that both **Union** and **Or** are same in this case?

Comment: @WhiteFlameAB Not really, because you can also have both. So it can be misunderstood, if we just use the word or. It is better to ask:" What is the probability of getting a head **and/or** a 4 ?" This includes more clearly the case, that also both cases can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring ​ P(Getting Heads **and** 4) .

P(A **or** B) ​ + ​ P(A **and** B) ​ ​ ​ = ​ ​ ​ P(A) + P(B)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as 3 different scenarios where it can be P(Heads or 4):

Scenario One: P(4 and not Heads): (1/6) * (1/2) = 1/12
Scenario Two: P(Heads and not 4): (5/6) * (1/2) = 5/12
Scenario Three: P(Heads and 4): (1/6) * (1/2) = 1/12

Add up these three scenarios and you get 5/12 + 1/12 + 1/12 which equals to 7/12.